# Why sbt resolver with Resolver method doesn't work?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I've installed a jarjar:jarjar:1.0 in my local maven repo, and my build.sbt is

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "jarjar" % "jarjar" % "1.0"

resolvers += Resolver.file("maven-l", file("/Volumes/Data/Repo/Maven"))
```

It says jarjar cannot be resolved, and show resolvers gives:

```
> show resolvers
[info] List(FileRepository(maven-l,FileConfiguration(true,None),sbt.Patterns@30ea6dbc))
```

This does not look right.

Using

```
resolvers += "maven-l" at "/Volumes/Data/Repo/Maven"
```

It works just fine.

```
> show resolvers
[info] List(maven-l: /Volumes/Data/Repo/Maven)
```

I'm wondering why is this? is this a bug, or specified?
I'm using sbt 0.12.1

Reference: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers.html

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question on the sbt mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool